# How do a call a "sibling" validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, custom-validators

This seems like it should be really easy, but I can't figure out how to do it

I am working on a feature that (in short) allows this view here (http://www.agileventures.org/projects) to have images associated with project descriptions. This is achieved by the user submitting a url* to an image in the project create/edit view. I need to validate the image url in a number of ways, which are done at this point ...except for validating it as indeed being a URL.

In the last version, this value was verified from [app/models/project.rb] as

```
validates :image_url, uri: true, :allow_blank => true
```

because of my other validations, I need to move this functionality to [lib/validators/image_url.rb]. There is a 'sibling' validator [lib/validators/uri_validator]. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to call it.

The codebase is here: https://github.com/sidhene/WebsiteOne/tree/image_url
Help?

Comment: have you tried using *validate_with* method?

Comment: Won't that collide with the 'validate' function I need to call in the validator itself?

Comment: @Saravanan seems right. Instead of `validates :image_url...` you should be able to follow the pattern from `PivotalTrackerUrlValidator` and do `validate_with ImageUrlValidator`

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would say you should use `validate :image_url, uri: true` apart from calling your own validator (ImageUrlValidator) in `project.rb` as Saravanan suggested. If you are getting any errors when running your specs, plz post that error messages here and we can review them.

Comment: I think I'm going to just end up doing this. Its an extra line in project.rb, but it keeps the url validation separate and it works